# One issue with c++ macro expand

Tags: c++, c, macros

When I compile a cpp file using g++, gcc gives the follow error message:

> error: pasting "TBSYS_LOG_LEVEL_" and "-" does not give a valid preprocessing token

Then I check the source code, found out that there was three macro defines:

- In **fileA.h**:

> ```
> #define TBSYS_LOG_LEVEL_ERROR 0
> #define TBSYS_LOG(level, _fmt_, args...) ((TBSYS_LOG_LEVEL_##level>TBSYS_LOGGER._level) ? (void)0 : TBSYS_LOG_BASE(level, "[%ld] " _fmt_, pthread_self(), ##args))
> ```

- In **fileB.h**:

> ```
> #define ERROR -1
> ```

It turns out that "ERROR" was expand to "-1" before macro "TBSYS_LOG" expand.

The result after of expand "**TBSYS_LOG_LEVEL_##level**" was "**TBSYS_LOG_LEVEL_-1**", and finally cause the error message.

**BUT, as I know, the macro will not expand in this case. (When using ##)**

Then I wrote another cpp file to try this out:

> ```
> #define FOOBAR 100
> #define TEST(PARAM) FOO##PARAM
> #define BAR -1
>
> int main(){
>     cout<<TEST(BAR)<<endl; 
> }
> ```

This can pass the compile. And the output is 100.
These macro defines just like the former one, but not expand "BAR" to "-1", not cause an error message.

Is anyone knows why the macro expand in the former case?

---

**Update:** The code using TBSYS_LOG is :

> `TBSYS_LOG(ERROR, "expand data buffer failed, length: %d", bufsize);`

Comment: Your real code likely has an extra level of indirection through macros. It is at this extra level that `ERROR` got expanded. For example, if you do `#define TEST2(PARAM) TEST(PARAM)` and use `TEST2(BAR)`, you'll see this in action. Show how you use `TBSYS_LOG` macro.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define FOOBAR 100
#define TEST(PARAM) FOO##PARAM
#define BAR -1

int main(){
    cout<<TEST(BAR)<<endl; 
}
```

`##PARAM` denote the symbol itself. So `TEST(BAR)` here expand to be `FOO##BAR`(not the result, just for explanation), which is `FOOBAR`, which by `#define FOOBAR 100`, is 100.

`BAR` is never appeared as an independence symbol(separated by space or other delimiter), so no replacement as -1.

Answer (score 0):

FOO##PARAM will be expand at compile time, so before you run the code, the value to the macro has been fixed, it's FOOBAR, if you 
add a new param like this:

```
#define FOOBAR 100
#define TEST(PARAM) FOO##PARAM
#define BAR -1
#define GOOD 10

int main(){
    cout<<TEST(GOOD)<<endl; 
}
```

the compiler may never make it work for you.

Comment: This is because that "FOOGOOD" doesn't exist. TEST(GOOD) expand to "FOOGOOD", this is ok. The case in the question is like TEST(GOOD) expand to "FOO10".